# Make smaller button in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use bootstrap 3 buttons and I want to modify the size to smaller, I've tried with the following which doesn't work

```
.btn-sml {
    padding: 10px 10px;
    font-size: 22px;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
```

There is a better way to achieve this ?

Comment: reduce the font-size so that the button size will be reduced.

Comment: @vas I've tried it and it doesnt working...

Comment: i think u should use '.btn-sm'

Comment: use `.btn-xs` for smaller button

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Bootstrap provides four button sizes:

The classes that define the different sizes are:

```
.btn-lg
.btn-md
.btn-sm
.btn-xs // Removed in Bootstrap 4+
```

The following example shows the code for different button sizes:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Button Sizes</h2>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Large</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Medium</button>    
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Small</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems like Bootstrap 4 doesn't support `xs`

Comment: Yes, according to the documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/

Comment: really annoying. I need a smaller button

Comment: how to have button size different for devices ? For margin we have `mt-md-1 mt-2` means `margin-top` for `medium devices` is `1` and for mobile devices it is `2`.Can we have this for button ?

Comment: How to show a button as small-sized on small devices and large-sized on large devices? There isn't anything like `btn-lg---lg` or `btn-lg---sm`. I can control paddings but not e.g. font-size.

Comment: just edit bootstrap css and make it support it

Answer (score 57):

Manually setting the padding in y-direction to 0 and adding an inline-style to reduce the font size gave me an xs-Button in Bootstrap 4:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary py-0" style="font-size: 0.8em;">
```

Comment: I took the font-size part and place it in the main css so that all of them change at once (invented a new class ```btn-mini``` to put after py-0), which overrides ```btn-sm``` the same way py-0 does.

Comment: I added px-0 for even more compactness.

Answer (score 8):

You can use badge style links, they look and behave like buttons:

```css
.badge-sm {
    min-width: 1.8em;
    padding: .25em !important;
    margin-left: .1em;
    margin-right: .1em;
    color: white !important;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<label class="mx-1 text-dark">Buttons:</label>
<a href="#" class="badge badge-primary badge-sm" data-scale="hour" data-value="1">1</a>
<a href="#" class="badge badge-danger badge-sm" data-scale="hour" data-value="2">2</a>
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does and how it does it; never just post code on its own.

Comment: I think you have not answered what user want. He asked solution for small buttons, while you answered usage of badge component. We should try to give solution nearest to user approach. For example, you can provide https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#btn-dropdowns-sizing to answer this question.

Comment: +1, it doesn't matter what HTML component you use IMO, if it looks and behaves like a tiny button, it's a tiny button.

I would also recommend adding "cursor: pointer;" to the styling so you get the cursor hover effect a button would have.

Comment: this solutions also works very nice in boostrap 5

Answer (score 4):

You can easily make your buttons smaller using the `height` property in Bootstrap 4.

For example:

```css
.btn-sml { height: 4vh; } /* change the value according to your need. */
```

Comment: Is it the same answer for bootstrap 3 and 4?